# Inserir quadrado em legenda googlemaps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

Estou tentando adicionar uma legenda em meu mapa do googlemaps.
Para montar a legenda eu criei um quadrado com a cor que representa um valor.
css:

```
.square{
    width: 48%;
    height: 0;              /* Quadrado */
    padding-bottom: 48%; 
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.block{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;                  /* Colorido*/
  background: #00FFFF;
  width: 3%;
  height: 3%;
}
```

css quadro da legenda:

```
 #legend {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid #000;
      }
```

JavaScript para adicionar a legneda ao mapa:

```
var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.className ="block";
          div.innerHTML = 'Valor do quadrado';
          legend.appendChild(div);
        gmap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
```

O meu resultado é um quadro de legenda apenas com o texto,sem o quadrado ao lado.
Imagino que a razão é por eu não ter um css para o texto ficar ao lado do quadrado.

Problema:

**-Propriedade do css para colocar o texto a partir do quadrado.
-No JS que passei a eu adiciono a div.classname="block",mas falta a div square,caso eu faça dois appendChild eu consigo adicionar as duas divs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a melhor forma de você injetar o quadrado no seu elemento, seria usar um **pseudoelemento** no seu **css**. Ex:

```
#legend:before{
content:'';
position:relative;
left:0;
display:inline-block;
width:48%;height:0;  
}
```

Dessa forma a responsabilidade fica no css e você não precisar fazer via javascript, você pode até pensar fazer a legenda assim também, caso ele não seja mutável.

Onde o **valor** da "**propriedade content**" seria a **string** da legenda. Ex: `#legend:after{content:'Aqui o texto da legenda';}`